# Kafka AMQ Stream - Topics command

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, amq

I've never used AMQ Streams (Kafka). How can I connect to topics through the route (read/create/delete)? With Kafka, for example from my local machine, I used the CLI with the basic command. But with AMQ Streams I have only the route. It is a HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the AMQ Streams Operator to run your Pods. There is a good explanation in the [following blog post](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/30/accessing-kafka-part-3/) on how to use OpenShift Routes to connect to Kafka.

The Route can be exposed by defining it in the `Kafka` object like so:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    # ...
    listeners:
      # ...
      external:
        type: route
    # ...
```